# What is the post function behind form submitting?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http

I am curious to know the function implementation of `form` submitting using `post` method or how it works?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. What do you mean by "function implementation of `form`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource
```

When you press button (usually it is type="submit") you send some data do server side. With Post method you can in code behind (server side) to do you job with data. Usually you will work with specified named data (like inputs for example).

I suggest you to look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).

> It's the method the browser uses to talk to the server when asking for
>   a response that takes into account the data provided in the body of
>   the HTTP request: "Hey server, take a look at this data and send me
>   back an appropriate result." If a form is sent using this method, the
>   data is appended to the body of the HTTP request.